# how to use setFillColor in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

How to use setFillColor in FPDF?
I tried this, but it does not work:

```
$pdf->setFillColor(230,220,0);
```

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: i used:  $pdf->setFillColor(230,220,0);

Answer (score 2):

It's SetFillColor. The `S` is capital. So, it should be `$pdf->SetFillColor`

Comment: @Elon Glad to help :)